# Publishing array data with rqt

Tags: ros, ros2, array, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the rqt message publisher to publish a message of type `std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray`.

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to give the `data` field of type `sequence<double>`. The default value in the expression field suggests that one should simply specify the array initializer in the `array('d')` constructor. I tried this to no avail with: `array('d', [0.1, 0.1])`

```
>>> [ERROR] [1644749632.166618229] [get_message_class]: Malformed message_type: sequence<double>
Python eval failed for expression "array('d', [0.1, 0.1])" with an exception "name 'array' is not defined"
Publisher._evaluate_expression(): failed to evaluate expression: "array('d', [0.1, 0.1])" as Python type "None"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rqt_publisher/publisher.py", line 161, in change_publisher
    new_text = handler(self._publishers[publisher_id], topic_name, new_value)
  File "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rqt_publisher/publisher.py", line 262, in _change_publisher_expression
    expression, error_prefix, slot_type.__name__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

The interesting bit here is what seems to be the root cause of the problem:

```
Python eval failed for expression "array('d', [0.1, 0.1])" with an exception "name 'array' is not defined"
```

If this isn't the correct way to do it, what am I supposed to do? I also tried, all in vain, these options:

```
[0.1, 0.1]
array.array('d', [0.1, 0.1])
import array; array.array('d', [0.1, 0.1])
```

I'm using ROS2 Rolling at the moment, although I've had the same issue with Foxy and Galactic before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396080/publishing-array-data-with-rqt/) by [kvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/93531/kvik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The version **1.6.0** of [rqt_publisher](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_publisher/commit/55d75d72d9c213de8fdec57c5d1647e1732f9744) solve the problem. I tested also in foxy using this version and is working fine with the expression

> array('d', [0.1, 0.1])

---

Originally posted by [halejo](https://answers.ros.org/users/116843/halejo/) with karma: 26 on 2022-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/93531/kvik/) on 2022-09-06**:
Nice. Thanks for the tip.